# user permission list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can anybody help me on this?

How to get the database level permission users list for a particular database in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: And do a quick Google search first, too

Answer (score 4):

Simple [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=606&q=sql+server+2005+list+permissions&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CMZWeHZPeTI3sF4iwyASx58i7DgAAAKoEBU_Qefs4) search, with query taken from [the first result](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/02/09/SQL-Server-2005_3A00_-View-all-permissions.aspx):

```
 select dp.NAME AS principal_name,
         dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
         o.NAME AS object_name,
         p.permission_name,
         p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
 from    sys.database_permissions p
 left    OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects o
 on     p.major_id = o.OBJECT_ID
 inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
 on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
```

Modified slightly to include the database name as well:

```
select dp.NAME AS principal_name,
    dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
    o.NAME AS object_name,
    p.permission_name,
    p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc,
    d.[name] as database_name
from sys.database_permissions p
left OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects o on p.major_id = o.OBJECT_ID
inner JOIN sys.database_principals dp on p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
left outer JOIN sys.sysdatabases d on d.sid = dp.sid
```

Comment: +1 It's unusual to credit Google tho I guess half of SO is experienced developers doing Google searches for less experienced developers :) haha